# Functions to filter and sum delimited incoming data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following incoming data:

| Date | Data | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/21 | Red: 10 | 01 |
| 03/21 | Blue: 5 | 02 |
| 04/21 | Red: 20, Blue: 15 | 03 |
| 04/21 | Green: 7 | 04 |
| 04/21 | Red: 13, Green: 15 | 05 |

I have managed to separate the data into its components as shown below:

| Date | Data | ID | Color 1 | Value 1 | Color 2 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/21 | Red: 10 | 01 | Red | 10 |  |  |
| 03/21 | Blue: 5 | 02 | Blue | 5 |  |  |
| 04/21 | Red: 20, Blue: 15 | 03 | Red | 20 | Blue | 15 |
| 04/21 | Green: 7 | 04 | Green | 7 |  |  |
| 04/21 | Red: 13, Green: 15 | 05 | Red | 13 | Green | 15 |

I want to create a function that looks at each month and sums the values for each color. An example is below:

| Date | Red | Blue | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/21 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 04/21 | 13 | 0 | 22 |

I have absolutely no control over the incoming data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you separate the data?

Comment: A function to this effect: =LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(E342,SEARCH(",",E342)-1),E342),SEARCH(":",IFERROR(LEFT(E342,SEARCH(",",E342)-1),E342))-1)

Comment: Starting with your incoming data, I would use Power query to separate your data into `Date`, `Color` and `Value` columns. Then `Group` by `Date` and `Color` with the `Sum` operation. Finally Pivot on the color column with a `Sum` aggregation

Comment: red april should be 33 and blue april 15, right?

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> you can directly achieve your desired output without any helper table. Use nested `FILTERXML()` formula with `Textjoin()`. As per my below screenshot use below formula to <kbd>F2</kbd> cell.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$6=$E2,$B$2:$B$6,"")),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '"&F$1&"')]"),": ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),0))
```

For date column to extract unique dates/month you can use `UNIQUE()` function to `E2` cell,

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A6)
```

[image]

Here is detailed explanation of [FILTERXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) function from @JvdV.